# How does ipa-client know when IPA Fail Over occurs during Multi Master setup?

Tags: freeipa

I have setup a multi-master IPA and it seems to be working fine.

So it seems like for this kind of a setup, we don't need to mention the --server option and only the --domain option should work fine.

( Please correct me if I'm wrong )

So for such cases, I had 2 doubts :-

i) So now ideally how will IPA-Client know whether a Fail Over occurs ?

ii) Generally for many OS like Amazon Linux, there is no ipa-client and we have a workaround with sssd. So how is it possible in such cases to have a failover in-case primary master fails ?

Answer (score 1):

ipa-client-install only configures SSSD, so after the fact it is SSSD which actially handles failover. You can read the documentation in SSSD (sssd-ipa, sssd-ldap manual pages, sections "Failover" and "Service discovery" and setup it the same way as ipa-client-install does.

Another part is configuration of Kerberos. In krb5.conf you can either do SRV record-based discovery of KDC or specify multiple entries for 'kdc = server1..n' as part of the realm stanza.